# Python Dictionary in Comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

Given a Dictionary:

```
operating_hrs = {'MONDAY': 8, 'TUESDAY': 6, 'WEDNESDAY': 5, 'THURSDAY': 8, 'FRIDAY': 3, 'SATURDAY': 5.25, 'SUNDAY': 0}
```

> day = "FRIDAY"

**I want to get the value of FRIDAY which is 3. But I got an error or empty value.**

Try #1:

```
[v for v in operating_hrs.values() if day == v][0]
```

> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
> ----> 1 [v for v in operating_hrs.values() if day == x][0]
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Try #2:

```
[v for v in operating_hrs.values() if day == v]
```

> [ ]

Try #3:

```
[v[0] for v in operating_hrs.values() if day == v]
```

> [ ]

Comment: Did you mean: `operating_hrs[day]`?   **edited**

Comment: From where you're getting `day`?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected my question. day = "FRIDAY"

Comment: Please, post [mre]. Provide a snippet(s) we can easily copy/paste and run. And why comprehension when trying to access value for a single key?

Comment: The tag `dictionary-comprehension` seems incorrect as well, as all the OP's examples are  [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the value of a key in dict, simply:

```
operating_hrs[key]
operating_hrs.get(key) #in case the key might not exist, to avoid KeyError
```

You don't need list comprehension / iteration to access dict value for a key

Answer (score 0):

You can access `dictionary` item like this:

```py
v = operating_hrs["FRIDAY"]
```

You're using the wrong method i.e. You're comparing the `v` with the values of the dictionary not the keys of the dictionary.

> `operating_hrs.values()` returns the list of dictionary values.

```py
li = list(operating_hrs.values())
>>> [8, 6, 5, 8, 3, 5.25, 0]
```

**To get the list of dictionary keys use the `keys()` function**

```py
li = list(operating_hrs.keys())
>>> ['MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY']
```

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone else said, just use .get() or operating_hrs[day]. However, to do it iteratively:

`[operating_hrs[v] for v in operating_hrs.keys() if day == v]` should work.

You're mixing up .values() and .keys().

.keys() gives you the key, which in your case is the day.
.values() gives you the value, which in your case is the number.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries operate different from lists. You can't iterate over them with indexes.

If you want to iterate the old fashioned way, you need to get the keys and then iterate over those.

```
keys = operating_hrs.keys()
for key in keys: 
  value = operating_hrs[key] 
  *your code*
```

If you want to get key value from a different source, you can test if its a key and then get the value

```
if key in operating_hrs.keys():
  value = operating_hrs[key]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That is incorrect in Python3. To iterate over a dictionary's keys, you simply have to use a for loop: `for i in operating_hrs`. If you want to iterate over the keys and values at the same time use (in Python3): `for d, h in operating_hrs.items()`. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques)

Comment: Yes you can also use a normal for loop, but since its a questions about the understanding of dicts, it would be better to do simple steps

Comment: You said `If you want to itterate the old fashioned way you need to get the keys and itterate with them`. That's not correct, you don't need to explicitly call `.keys()` to iterate over a dictionary's keys. Not calling `.keys()` is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

dictionary.values() will yield a list of values so precisely you're comparing `FRIDAY`  with `8,6,5...` and hence you're getting empty list. The while purpose of dictionary is to have O(1) or constant time lookup and can be simply done by  `operating_hrs[day]` or `operating_hrs.get(day)` . You don't have a loop into the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but as others have pointed out, if you know the dictionary's key that holds the value that you want, you can simply use:

```py
operating_hrs = {'MONDAY': 8, 'TUESDAY': 6, 'WEDNESDAY': 5, 'THURSDAY': 8, 'FRIDAY': 3, 'SATURDAY': 5.25, 'SUNDAY': 0}
operating_hrs['FRIDAY']
3
```

If you *must* use a list comprehension, then you could use something like:

```
day = 'FRIDAY'
hrs_friday = [h for d, h in operating_hrs.items() if d == day ][0]
print(hrs_friday)
3
```